# Typescript, static method inheritance

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript2.0

I'm working with typescript and I have a problem with the static inheritance between classes

Can anyone explain me the result of the following :

```
class Foo {
    protected static bar: string[] = [];

    public static addBar(bar: string) {
        this.bar.push(bar);
    }

    public static logBar() {
        console.log(this.bar);
    }
}

class Son extends Foo {
    protected static bar: string[] = [];
}

class Daughter extends Foo {}

Foo.addBar('Hello');
Son.addBar('World');
Daughter.addBar('Both ?');
Foo.logBar();
Son.logBar();
Daughter.logBar();
```

current result :

```
[ 'Hello', 'Both ?' ]
[ 'World' ]
[ 'Hello', 'Both ?' ]
```

but I want :

```
[ 'Hello' ]
[ 'World' ]
[ 'Both ?' ]
```

Do I have a solution without redeclare the static `bar` property ?

Thanks !

Comment: remove the *static*

Comment: Removing the `static` leaves the property bound to an instance rather than the type. OP wants the property bound to the type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A very detailed explanation of the behavior in the OPs code is found in [answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43417124/typescript-static-method-%20inheritance/43417244#43417220) by @T.J.Crowder.

To avoid the need to redefine the static member you can take this approach:

```
class Foo {
    private static bar = new Map<string, string[]>();

    public static addBar(bar: string) {
        let list: string[];

        if (this.bar.has(this.name)) {
            list = this.bar.get(this.name);
        } else {
            list = [];
            this.bar.set(this.name, list);
        }

        list.push(bar);
    }

    public static logBar() {
        console.log(this.bar.get(this.name));
    }
}

class Son extends Foo {}

class Daughter extends Foo {}

Foo.addBar('Hello');
Son.addBar('World');
Daughter.addBar('Both ?');
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20bar%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%5B%5D%3E()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20addBar(bar%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20list%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(this.bar.has(this.name))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list%20%3D%20this.bar.get(this.name)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.bar.set(this.name%2C%20list)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list.push(bar)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20logBar()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.bar.get(this.name))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Son%20extends%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Daughter%20extends%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AFoo.addBar('Hello')%3B%0D%0ASon.addBar('World')%3B%0D%0ADaughter.addBar('Both%20%3F')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AFoo.logBar()%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%5B%20'Hello'%2C%20'Both%20%3F'%20%5D%0D%0ASon.logBar()%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%5B%20'World'%20%5D%0D%0ADaughter.logBar()%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%5B%20'Hello'%2C%20'Both%20%3F'%20%5D))

Comment: Remember that `Map` can have non-string keys, so you could just key by the constructor itself... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder True. But I always prefer using a "string id" unless I actually need the instance (the constructor in this case) for other things. It's probably a preference I carry from other languages.

Comment: @NitzanTomer Make sure you configure your minifier not to mangle function names. We got bit by this. You really should use the constructor reference since two classes from different modules could have the same name. https://www.uglifyjs.net/#toggle_text_mangle_fnames

Answer (score 29):

The key thing to understand about `static` and `class` is that the constructor function of the subclass **inherits** from the constructor function of the superclass. Literally. `class` doesn't *just* set up inheritance between instances created by the constructors, the constructors *themselves* are also in an inheritance structure.

`Foo` is the prototype of `Son` and `Daughter`. That means that `Daughter.bar` **is** `Foo.bar`, it's an inherited property. But you gave `Son` its *own* `bar` property, with its own array, so looking up `bar` on `Son` finds `Son`'s own `bar`, not the one on `Foo`. Here's a simpler example of that happening:

```js
class Foo { }
class Son extends Foo { }
class Daughter extends Foo { }

Foo.bar = new Map([["a", "ayy"]]);
console.log(Foo.bar.get("a"));          // "ayy"

// `Son` inherits `bar` from `Foo`:
console.log(Son.bar === Foo.bar);       // true, same Map object
console.log(Son.bar.get("a"));          // "ayy"

// So does `Daughter` -- for now
console.log(Daughter.bar === Foo.bar);  // true, same Map object
console.log(Daughter.bar.get("a"));   // "ayy"

// Retroactively giving `Son` its own static `bar`
Son.bar = new Map();
console.log(Son.bar === Foo.bar);       // false, different Map objects
console.log(Son.bar.get("a"));          // undefined
```

That's why you see `["Hello", "Both ?"]` when you look at `Foo.bar` and `Daughter.bar`: It's the same `bar`, pointing at the same array. But you only see `["World"]` on `Son.bar`, because it's a different `bar` pointing at a different array.

To separate them, you probably want to give each constructor its own `bar`, although you *could* do what [Nitzan Tomer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43417244/157247) with a `Map`.

---

A bit more detail on how things are organized. It's a bit like this:

```js
const Foo = {};
Foo.bar = [];
const Son = Object.create(Foo);
Son.bar = []; // Overriding Foo's bar
const Daughter = Object.create(Foo);
Foo.bar.push("Hello");
Son.bar.push("World");
Daughter.bar.push("Both ?");
console.log(Foo.bar);
console.log(Son.bar);
console.log(Daughter.bar);
```

This is a very surprising thing if you come to it fresh, but your three classes look something like this in memory:

```
                                                        +−−>Function.prototype
                                     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
Foo−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−+−>|   (function)  |  |
                               / /   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                               | |   | [[Prototype]] |−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−+
                               | |   | bar           |−−−−−>|  (array)  |
                               | |   | addBar, etc.  |      +−−−−−−−−−−−+
                               | |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      | length: 2 |
                               | |                          | 0: Hello  |
                               | |                          | 1: Both ? |
                               | |                          +−−−−−−−−−−−+
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   | |
Daughter−−>|   (function)  |   | |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   | |
           | [[Prototype]] |−−−+ |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     |
                                 |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     |
Son−−−−−−−>|   (function)  |     |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     |
           | [[Prototype]] |−−−−−+  +−−−−−−−−−−−+
           | bar           |−−−−−−−>|  (array)  |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+        +−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                    | length: 1 |
                                    | 0: World  |
                                    +−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Comment: You say "that link with Foo is broken" but I think the technical term is "shadowed", right?  That is, `Foo.bar` and `Son.bar` are two separate objects and `Foo.bar` is still in `Son.bar`'s prototype chain, but the child object *shadows* the parent's object, in the same way that an inner scope can shadow a variable in an outer scope.  (I say "I think" because I'm not an expert, but it's how I understand things and it helped me a lot.)

Comment: @Coderer - I've don't think I've heard the term *shadowed* used with object properties (just variables in nested scope), but it is conceptually similar, yes. Because `Son` has its own `bar`, looking up `bar` on `Son` stops when it finds it on `Son` and doesn't continue along the prototype chain; that's very similar to nested identifier resolution. So I haven't heard it used that way, but...I think it works, sure. :-) Re *"...`Foo.bar` and `Son.bar` are two separate objects and `Foo.bar` is still in `Son.bar`'s prototype chain..."* I don't think you meant to have those `.bar`s on there, right?

Comment: Yes, too late for me to edit, but I meant that to read "`Foo.bar` is in `Son`'s prototype chain", as in `Son` has access to `Son.bar` and `Foo.bar`, if you're in a context where you can use `super` to bypass your own prototype and look further up the chain.